# Is it possible to exhance bitcoins to real money?

Tags: client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change BTC into normal cash?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/how-can-i-change-btc-into-normal-cash)

If I sell things on the internett and using bitcoins, how can I get transfered the "coins" to real money?

Comment: Can I know your definition of "real money" first please?

Comment: Hi Empty! This was closed as a duplicate of another question. If the duplicate question does not exactly answer your question there are a lot of other similar questions. For example, have a look under the tag [exchanges](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchanges).

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many methods:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins