# How do I echange bitcoins into $ or Euros?

Tags: exchanges, currencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change BTC into normal cash?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/how-can-i-change-btc-into-normal-cash)

I sold items / goods for bitcoins
How do I eventually exchange these bitcoins for $ or Euro ?

Comment: You do it at any one of the services listed at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Currency_exchanges.

Comment: You can automate this process using the exchange APIs - the [XChange](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange) project provides a consolidated approach.